# Error when using Django Redirect View + Google Oauth Flow

Tags: python, django, django-views, google-oauth

I am building a Django app that requires API access to Gmail and Google Calendar.  I'm following [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) provided by Google.  When I can get the correct authentication URI via command line, like so:

```
>>> from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
>>> from integrations.google import settings
>>> flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
...     client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
...     client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
...     scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
...     redirect_uri='http://www.myapp.com/oauth/google/',
...     ) 
>>> url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
>>> url
'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.readonly&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myapp.com%2Foauth%2Fgoogle%2F&response_type=code&client_id=123345789.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline'
```

This URL points to the correct page ("MyApp would like to: View your emails, messages and settings...", etc.) so oauth2client library appears to be working as expected.

The problem seems to pop up when I write incorporate Django's RedirectiView; the URL becomes malformed and I get a 404 error from Google:

[image]

> Error: invalid_scope
>
> Some requested scopes were invalid.
>   {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly], invalid=[ ]}

So it looks like somehow additional whitespace is being added to the 'scope' variable, or possibly an additional 'scope' variable is being added?  I'm not really sure why this error is coming up, but again it is **only** popping up when I'm calling it via RedirectView.get_redirect_uri

Here is my view:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from integrations.google import settings


class GetGoogleAuthURIView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
            client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
            redirect_uri='http://www.perryapp.com/oauth/google/',
            )

        url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

        return url
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post a complete stack trace?

Comment: @twil Added a screenshot of the 404 page that I'm getting.  Any takeaways from it?

Comment: The `%0A++++++++++++++++` part of the `scope` looks strange (look at the address bar). Like you have a new line somethere. Sorry, can't reproduce.

Comment: I wonder if the oauth2client library is doing something strange behind the scenes. Not sure if this will work, but did you try passing a tuple of strings to the scope parameter of OAuth2WebServerFlow instead of a string? It seems like you can: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/client.py#L1936

Comment: @RevolutionTech thanks for the suggestion, but I did verify that oauth2client library is performing as expected; it returns the correct Oauth URL.  I've updated my post above to show this.

Comment: That's interesting. Does this issue also happen if you use a HttpResponseRedirect in a function-based view?

Comment: it should be `scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'] `not combined